Worth replacing greenboard for shower wall
so my soap dish fell off the other day and I noticed this green stuff behind it. I looked it up and found that it's something called greenboard and found it is suboptimal to use for showers as it's not waterproof. The shower isn't very new and the grout is patchy so I'm pretty sure water will have gotten through.
Is it worth taking this opportunity to just go ahead and redo the shower walls with something more robust?


Moisture/water inside walls is never good.  Depending on the amount of time it has happen, the job might turn out bigger than just replacing drywall/tiles.  Might be lucky and not find any mold or rotten studs, but be prepared to find it.

Unless you're looking for a reason to redo the shower, it doesn't appear to have enough damage to justify ripping out three walls and adding cement board and new tile. The grout lines look pretty good from what I can see. I'd be cutting out that piece of green board and checking out what's behind it for more clues of moisture getting in there. If it looks dry, build up the area and reinstall the soap dish.

I hate greenboard. In my opinion, tile showers should always have a proper tile backerboard (concrete fiberboard is my favorite). I've seen a few extreme rot situations caused by improper tile backing, and the worst was greenboard.
But: in all those cases, damage was clearly evident so I had to do something about it, and replacing the walls and tile was expensive and time-consuming.
If you don't see damage already (I don't see anything in your photo) you'd have to make the call whether you're ready for the expense and time investment in re-doing the wall.
The easy fix in your case is to scrape caulk around the edges and use an adhesive to re-adhere the soap dish, then caulk around it with silicone caulk. You could also seal your grout so more water doesn't get through; but any water/mold that may already be in there won't be able dry out as well through the seal either, so that's a toss-up.

The size and shape of the tile makes me think you have about a 35 year old shower/tub combo.  That's pretty old. As others said you could probably just do some repairs and get that soap dish reinstalled and keep your 35 year old shower.
However if you would want to repair things and bring them into the 21st century you could opt to remove just the tiled walls and replace the backer with cement board. Here is a good video showing how to remove just the tile walls, Replacing a tile surround. Done right you can have the new tile cover the seam between drywall and cement board and not need to do any drywall work.  (be aware you should tape the seams of cement board with approved cement board tape and mud seams and screw holes. Then cover with a waterproofing agent like AquaDefense or similar.  Choose your tiles and get the proper grout and thinset. (Tile Store pros can help with this.)
What will it cost?  We don't answer those questions here. However here is a link to a Cost estimating site that will let you put in your zip code and get a pricing range for your location. This will show both average labor and materials cost.
If you choose to go this route and have more questions, come back here and post them as new questions.
